# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input after Delete request Rails7/React

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

I am building a basic React application utilizing a Rails api for school.  Its a videogame review website.  The application is properly rendering my reviews and each of their respective delete buttons.  When I click the button, I get the following error:

VM513:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Reviews.js:23:1

After I rerender, the page is free of the deleted review so I know its my request that is successful.  Obviously the response is the issue.  My database type is postgresql through render I am not sure if that is affecting anything.

I don't think you need the seeds or schema as I feel the issue is somewhere in the code below:

```
//reviews.js delete request
    function handleDeleteClick(id) {
        fetch(`reviews/${id}#destroy`, {method: "DELETE"}).then((r) => r.json());
    };
```

```
//reviews_controller.rb
...
    def create
        review = Review.create(review_params)
        render json: review, status: 201
    end
...
    def destroy
        review = find_review
        review.destroy
        head :no_content
    end

    private

    def find_review
        Review.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def review_params
        params.permit(:title, :user_id, :videogame_id, :rating, :body)
    end
```

Comment: don't need this `.then((r) => r.json())`. you're not rendering anything as a response: `head :no_content`.